# I can't install Apple Developer App on Big Sur 11.7

Tags: ios, swift, apple-developer

I want to develop my first iOS app on my MacBook (2013), and (tell me if im wrong) i saw that Apple Developer App is necessary.
The problem is, when I wanna download it on the App Store, it tells me "Developer App cant be installed on “what ever” because macOS 12 or later is necessary".

Can you help me ?
I have to buy a most recent MacBook to have a most recent version of macOS to be able to install Apple Developer App?
Is this app really necessary ?
Is there a trick to install an older version ?

Explain me everything you can please. ://

Ty for your help !

I tried to find an older version of Apple Developer App on the web. I didn't find.

Comment: What do you need the [Apple Developer](https://apps.apple.com/gb/app/apple-developer/id640199958) app for? You can watch all WWDC videos online as well if that's what you want to do in the app.

Answer (score 1):

What you mean Apple Developer App is Xcode?
You can find older version of Xcode App in https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=Xcode%2012

Comment: I think OP means the [Apple Developer](https://apps.apple.com/gb/app/apple-developer/id640199958) app, which contains the WWDC videos.

Comment: Yes, like @DávidPásztor said, I'm talking about The Apple Developer app. I thought this app was necessary to build an app with Xcode.

Comment: @Tom no, you only need Xcode itself to build iOS apps. The sole purpose of the Apple Developer app is watching/downloading/bookmarking WWDC videos.